# Jumah Khutbah Guide

Tags: sunni, jumuah, khutbah

I want complete detailed steps on khutbah right from start (stand , say assalamualaikum, sit , athan, stand and say in Arabic etc) to the end (wa aqeemussalah) with references (Hadith or Quran).
I have searched a lot on the internet but they all have their own guidelines without references. I need it as I have no background in khutbah delivery and I need to deliver in my university.

Note:I don't intend to know the topics like how many people are required, the validity of the place etc. I want to know what all the khateeb( related to fardh) has to do basically. I don't mind if you add something which is extra (Sunnah) in your answer but please mention if it's an extra portion.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever we see in Friday Prayer (Specially Khutbah) is correct way because there is no contradiction between any Imam.

If you want to explore [see all the hadith on Jummah (Friday Prayer)](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=jummah)

Verse (62:2)

> It is He who has sent among the unlettered a Messenger from themselves
>   reciting to them His verses and purifying them and teaching them the
>   Book and wisdom - although they were before in clear error

Verse (62:9)

> O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for
>   the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the
>   remembrance of Allah and leave trade. That is better for you, if you
>   only knew.

Verse (62:10)

> And when the prayer has been concluded, disperse within the land and
>   seek from the bounty of Allah, and remember Allah often that you may
>   succeed.

For deep understanding, try to understand the complete Surah Jummah (62) with Tafseer.